# Using generic views with HTTP verbs

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to mix HTTP verbs with Django's Built-in class-based generic views, i understand that is a good pattern (correct me if not) to keep Url's like app/pets/ and use HTTP's verbs to define what to do (GET, POST/create, PUT/update, DELETE/delete, etc) instead of something like app/pets/add or app/pets/delete as Django's documentation shows when using [generic views with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms)

So i tried something like this:

urls.py:

```
    path('login/', views.sign_in, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.log_out, name='logout'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('pets/', views.Pet.as_view(), name= "pets"),
```

Views.py

```
class Pet(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url= "/vet/login/"

    #handle Get Request
    class PetListView(ListView):
        model= models.Pet
        context_object_name= "pets"
        template_name= "vet/index.html"

    #Handle Put request
    class PetUpdateView():
        pass
```

but i am getting and error of 405 method not allowed (and i think is not a good practice do this).

i also tried this (defining the PetListView same as above):

```
class Pet(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url= "/vet/login/"

    def get(self, request):
        return HttpResponse(PetListView.as_view())
```

But this just print the object on the screen.

I am new to Django and i do not know what is the better approach to accomplish this using Django generic's views since it reduce a lot code for CRUD operations

Comment: Is this regular django or django rest framework?

Comment: Is regular django

Comment: You need a separate class for each of the CRUDL operations. They should not be inner classes of your "main" view. Unfortunately, regular Django does not support viewsets like DRF. In summary, you can assign whatever view to whatever URL in the urls.py which can fit your request in the post.

Comment: ok, so if i want to keep the http verps i should have to do the implementations in the "main" view defining the functions get,post, etc, right? no way to use the generics implementations? i mean, if a use generics views i have to add in the urls.py paths like pet/add, pet/update, etc

Comment: Yes, if you want to follow the REST convention and use the verbs, you should have one view which defines all methods. However, be aware of the limitations of the browsers. Usually, they only distinguish "post" and "get". So, if you take a look at the code of `DeleteView`, you'll see that the post method actually is a proxy of delete method.